# EF 6 Remove entity connected to read only view

Tags: entity-framework

I have two entities: one based on normal DB table and another base on DB View. They are connected one to many, like this:

[image: ef remove entity connected with read only view]

Entity City do not have store procedures mapped because for entity Country it is enough to have read only collection of Cities.
And cascade rule is not set.

But then I want to delete Country instance which have some Cities loaded I've received the following error:

> Unable to update the EntitySet because it has a
>   DefiningQuery and no 'DeleteFunction' element exists in the
>   'ModificationFunctionMapping' element to support the current
>   operation.

Which forcing me to create dummy stored procedure on DB and use it as Delete function, but it is an ugly solution.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Maybe you need to disable a [cascade delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete).

Comment: Cascade rule is not set. Question updated.